# Hover menu disappear too fast

Tags: html, css, bootstrapper

I got a problem, I do not know what is the problem with the hover menu but it disappears too fast

```
<div class="dropdown">
                        <li class="nav-item log-main">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown">Member</a>
                            <ul class=" dropdown-menu log">
                                <li><a href="sign_in.html" class="dropdown-item">Sign up</a></li>
                                <li><a href="log_in.html" class="dropdown-item">Log in</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </div>
```

css:

```
.navbar .nav-item ul.log{
display: none;
list-style-type:none;
}
.navbar .dropdown-menu:hover ul.log{
    display: block;
}
.log a{
    color:var(--main-text-color);
    font-family:var(--main-text-font);
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

Comment: because when you mouse off the link there is no hover and it hides

Comment: Be more specific in what you want to achieve.

Comment: This is the main limitation of using only CSS's `:hover` pseudo-class on a parent element for hover-menus. If you use a `@keyframes` animation and/or some scripting you can make it behave the same way as a native OS menu.

Comment: Please add all the relevant CSS & HTML. The current code you provided is not even creating any hover effect.

Comment: What do you mean by "disappearing too fast"? Do you mean that there is a problem with the menu e.g. it disappears when it shouldn't, or do you want to slow down the show/hide in an animation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `:hover` pseudo class on `.log-main:hover` to show the next `ul` which will be `.dropdown-menu`

**Live Demo:**

```css
.navbar .nav-item ul.log {
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.log-main:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.log a {
  color: var(--main-text-color);
  font-family: var(--main-text-font);
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="dropdown">
  <li class="nav-item log-main">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown">Member</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu log">
      <li><a href="sign_in.html" class="dropdown-item">Sign up</a></li>
      <li><a href="log_in.html" class="dropdown-item">Log in</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add hover to the element that is visible and the dropdown that is hidden.

```css
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu,
.dropdown .dropdown-menu:hover{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <ul class="navbar-nav">

    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```